# How to read file with characters and integers c++

Tags: c++

I am 90% done with a homework project of mine but this last step is kicking my butt.

I have a text file that I'm going to be reading from for my program with commands on each line.

Most of the commands are a single letter, but one of them is a letter with an integer behind it.

I ideally need to read the line, if it's just a char go right into a function I've already written for the "Command". If it has a specific character, "F" in this case, I need it to also read the integer that will be separated by a space and pass that into my other function for that command.

Example;

.txt file;

R
L
L
F 20
R
R

For those who are curious I'm mimicking the function of the Logo language that used the little "turtle" to make logo animations for my homework.

*Edit*
I did try researching some methods to do this but most that I came up with either grabbed just the one char, or involved strings with which I could pull each "line" but then have to read and convert what was in string to separate char and int. If that is truly the "best" way to do it I'll suck it up and do it but I wanted to see if there was something that wasn't initially obvious to me.

Comment: Can we see the 90%? And did you research that? Logic would be: While(reading), FileIn >> someVariable, then check someVariable, if it is F then FileIn >> someOtherVariable .. else, call that function of yours .. etc

Comment: 1. Read the tokens with get line, if it is an 'F', add steps to an int.

Comment: If the last step is kicking your butt, you're going to need to work with a classmate. There's no easy way to kick your *own* butt. Of course, you could try to convince your educational institution that this last step is not germane to the quality of the code :-)

Comment: I moved your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my approach:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream readFromFile("test.txt");
    vector<string> fileWords;

    string word;

    while (readFromFile >> word) {

        try {
            int number = stoi(word); // here is your number
            cout << number << endl;
        } catch (const invalid_argument& exception) {
            cout << exception.what() << endl; // just for debug
        }

        fileWords.emplace_back(word);
    }

    for (const auto& word: fileWords) {
        cout << word << ' ';
    }

    readFromFile.close();
}
```

It reads word by word, saves it on an array and it also checks if a word is an integer (using the std::stoi function).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I'm trying to stay away from vectors as we've never gone over them and my professor purposefully will grade more harshly if we use concepts we haven't yet been taught. I will for sure however give it a shot.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

*Resolved* Kinda.
I ended up changing my fstream input to;

```
integer = 0;
char ch;
while(infile >> ch)
    if (ch == "F")
    {
        infile >> integer;
    }
// do stuff with code, I used a switch
```

Then after the switch I put I put integer back to 0.

This pulls the data I needed and stored it in the correct variables.